# Enabling/ disabling “select” if text input is empty or not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to disable a `<select>` depending on if text input is empty or not.

What I need is on page load is for the select to be enabled because the text inputs are empty, but once a date is entered to disable the select.

This is what I've got so far:

```
<ul>
    <li><label for="from_date">From Date:</label> <input type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date" value="<? print $_POST['from_date']; ?>" class="item_form_date" onchange="disableEl();" autocomplete="off" /></li>
    <li><label for="to_date">To Date:</label> <input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_date" value="<? print $_POST['to_date']; ?>" class="item_form_date" onchange="disableEl();" autocomplete="off" /></li>
    <li><label for="older_than">Or Older Than:</label> 
        <select name="older_than" id="older_than" class="input_tbl">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="1">1 Month</option>
        <option value="2">2 Month</option>
        <option value="3">3 Month</option>
        <option value="4">4 Month</option>
        <option value="5">5 Month</option>
        <option value="6">6 Month</option>
    </select>
    </li>
    <li><input type="submit" id="date_range" name="submit" class="" value="Apply" /></li>
</ul>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".item_form_date").change(function(e) {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            $("#older_than").removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $("#older_than").attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What browser? This works fine in chrome and firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work better the way you want it with `keyup`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".item_form_date").on("keyup change", function() {
        var checker = $.trim($(this).val()).length === 0;
        $("#older_than").attr('disabled', !checker);
    });
});
```

Oh, and if you want the `select` element `disabled` or not when you load the page, depending on whether the `input's` are populated or not, you can check that with your **PHP**:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="from_date">From Date:</label>
        <input type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date" value="<? print $_POST['from_date']; ?>" class="item_form_date" autocomplete="off" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="to_date">To Date:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_date" value="<? print $_POST['to_date']; ?>" class="item_form_date" autocomplete="off" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="older_than">Or Older Than:</label>

        <!-- this code -->
        <?php $disable = (trim($_POST['from_date']) == "" && trim($_POST['to_date']) == "") ? "" : " disabled"; ?>

        <select name="older_than" id="older_than" class="input_tbl"<?php echo $disable; ?>><!-- end of new feauture -->
            <option value="">Please Select</option>
            <option value="1">1 Month</option>
            <option value="2">2 Month</option>
            <option value="3">3 Month</option>
            <option value="4">4 Month</option>
            <option value="5">5 Month</option>
            <option value="6">6 Month</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li><input type="submit" id="date_range" name="submit" class="" value="Apply" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I like this approach! Any idea how to combine your solution with datepicker

Comment: If you mean how to mark as disabled the `select` element when a user pick a date from the calendar showed up by `datepicker`, then you should add the event `onchange` to the `onkey` function too, this line will be modified like this: `$(".item_form_date").on("keyup change", function() {`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to update as the user types, you need to use the `input` event.

http://jsfiddle.net/rfujjge6/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".item_form_date").on('input',function(e) {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            $("#older_than").removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $("#older_than").attr('disabled','');
        }
    });
});
```